# How do you negate a compound condition in SOQL?

Tags: soql

I currently have a SOQL statement which looks like so:

```
SELECT
   UPC__c
FROM
   Item_Status__c
WHERE
   Status__c in ('Void', 'OOS')
   AND Not_authorized__c = false
   AND (Response_Begin_Code__c = 'E' AND Response_Status_Code__c = 'NA')
```

But I actually want to select all records which **DO NOT** meet the criteria of the last condition.  So I want all records where **NOT** `(Response_Begin_Code__c = 'E' and Response_Status_Code__c = 'NA')`

**How do I write that in SOQL?**

I tried using both NOT before the compound condition:
 `AND NOT (Response_Begin_Code__c = 'E' AND Response_Status_Code__c = 'NA')`

and the negation operator !:
 `AND ! (Response_Begin_Code__c = 'E' AND Response_Status_Code__c = 'NA')`

But both were not permitted.

Now I do know that logically I can rewrite my condition by negating each test and changing the AND to an OR like so:

`AND (Response_Begin_Code__c != 'E' OR Response_Status_Code__c != 'NA')`

but would prefer not to if I can avoid it, since I think it is less apparent what is being asked.  I would prefer to be able to negate the entire compound condition.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add parentheses around your NOT.

```
SELECT
   UPC__c
FROM
   Item_Status__c
WHERE
   Status__c in ('Void', 'OOS')
   AND Not_authorized__c = false
   AND (NOT (Response_Begin_Code__c = 'E' AND Response_Status_Code__c = 'NA'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply turn:

```
AND (Response_Begin_Code__c = 'E' AND Response_Status_Code__c = 'NA')
```

into:

```
AND (Response_Begin_Code__c != 'E' OR Response_Status_Code__c != 'NA')
```

Comment: This isn't correct. In boolean algebra `x ^ y = ¬(¬x v ¬y)`. So the reverse should be `Response_Begin_Code__c != 'E' OR Response_Status_Code__c != 'NA'`.

Comment: I understand the boolean algebra, but I had thought he was actually asking something slightly different.  I updated my answer to be correct.